# Why do casting numbers on engine blocks matter?

Tags: engine

In [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24767/what-will-upgrading-the-camshaft-do-to-my-bbc-454) the OP references the block casting number his 454 GM motor.

Why is the block casting number relevant information when talking about an upgrade to an American V-8 engine?

Is this true for other motors made by Renault or Honda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of main purposes for knowing the casting number on a block. First, it is so you can know what has been put *into* the engine and what an engine is made out of before you start working on it or buy an engine to start working on it. You know the basis for the engine.

For instance, you see a Big Block Chevy (BBC) engine for sale. You go to take a look at it prior to purchase and what do you see but a short deck BBC GenIV engine. You don't know if it's a 396, 400, 402, 427, or a 454. How can you figure out what it is? They all look the same from the outside, so you look at the casting numbers. How do you know if the BBC you are looking at is a 2-bolt main or a 4-bolt main block? Do you know if it was made in 1968 or in 1990? These things matter when looking to purchase an engine so you know what you are getting into with it. You may ask why these things are important, but if you are serious about building an engine, you'd want to know these answers and the only way to tell is by the casting numbers.

One of the important details about all of this is knowing the *quality* of the block. Some blocks are made better than others. Some blocks have known casting defects or the metal used to make the block is better than others. Some blocks have Siamese bores (which means the cylinders actually come into contact with each other from the sides inside the water jackets which make them a lot stronger than blocks without). Some blocks have thicker cylinder walls than others. You won't be able to tell any of these things by looking at them, so you have a casting number which can tell you the particulars instead.

The second reason you'd want to know the casting numbers is if you are restoring a car. If you really want to get to the nitty-gritty of it, and want a numbers matching car, you'll need to know what engine block was in the car in the first place and then you go on the hunt. Usually finding a block which is exactly what you need to do your restoration is very hard. It can also be quite expensive. But if you're going to do it right, you need the casting number.